# Are vertical dog seat belts safe

Tags: dogs, safety

I saw a video of a vertical dog seatbelt that led through to Zugo Pet at https://zugopet.com/ these things would clearly help in an accident and could stop the dog jumping around but can they otherwise harm the dogs?

[image: This link is not playable follow the url to zugopet]

**Warning:** The play button does not do anything it was a screenshot from the website to help for the purpose clarification. :-)

Comment: Yep, I clicked on the play button... _sigh_

Answer (score 4):

### Car Safety

Care Safety is a necessity for any animal whether it be by carrier or seat belt. Since there are no regulations for car restraints for pets many companies can make false claims on their products.

[The Center For Pet Safety](http://www.centerforpetsafety.org/) is a non profit organization who does crash testing on the current seat belts and carriers in the market. Only a few products have passed the test.

### ZuGoPet

[ZuGoPet](http://www.centerforpetsafety.org/cps-certified/zugopet-rocketeer-pack/) are one of the VERY few seat belts that have been certified as safe, they have even contacted a Veterinary Orthopedic Surgeon to conclude that there will not be any injury to the pet for long-term use.

Letter to be found [here](http://www.centerforpetsafety.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Dr-Harari-Ltr.pdf)